# Custom font not showing proper in android ice cream sandwich version

Tags: android, fonts

[image]

[image]

Hi Guys,
In my app I have set a custom font, but the problem is android ice cream sandwich version not showing proper text or getting blurry, but In lollipop version its working fine. what is the problem in ice cream sandwich version any one knows?

For custom font I have used TypefaceManager class and below code

```
<com.ex.new.textstyleUtil.TypefaceTextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="normal"
                android:padding="@dimen/padding_2"
                android:text="@string/receiver_info"
                android:textColor="@color/mainColor"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_16" />



public void applyTypeface(TextView textView, TextStyle textStyle){
    final Typeface typeface = getTypeface(textView.getContext(), textStyle);
    if (typeface != null) {
        textView.setTypeface(typeface);
    }}

public class TypefaceTextView extends TextView {

public TypefaceTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypefaceManager.getInstance().applyTypeface(this, context, attrs);
}

/**
 * Convenience method in case I need to change the font from code as well.
 * @param textStyle
 */
public void setTextStyle(TextStyle textStyle) {
    TypefaceManager.getInstance().applyTypeface(this, textStyle);
}}


public enum CooperHewittTextStyle implements TextStyle {

NORMAL("normal", "CooperHewitt-Book.ttf"),
BOLD("bold", "CooperHewitt-Bold.ttf");

private String mName;
private String mFontName;

CooperHewittTextStyle(String name, String fontName) {
    mName = name;
    mFontName = fontName;
}

@Override
public String getFontName() {
    return mFontName;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return mName;
}}
```